# null value from bitmap created inside image loader

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a function that takes images from the library and presents them on the stage after loading.

```
function addStuff(){
    this["otherstuff" + index] = new Textfield;
    addChild(this["otherstuff" + index]);

    var IMAGE_URL:String = arraywithstuff[index][2];
    var ldr:Loader = new Loader();
    ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, ldr_complete);
    ldr.load(new URLRequest(IMAGE_URL));

    function ldr_complete(evt:Event):void {
        var bmp:Bitmap = ldr.content as Bitmap;
        this["photo" + index] = new Bitmap(bmp.bitmapData);
        addchild(this["photo" + index]);
```

Then I am later trying to remove the photo in another function

```
function removeStuff(){
    for (var i = 0; i<maxindex; i++){
        removeChild(this["otherstuff" + i]);
        removeChild(this["photo" + i]);
    }
```

This works for the stuff I am creating outside of the loader, like textboxes, but the images won't dissapear. I get this error: `Parameter child must be non-null.`

Comment: It is possible that you change **index** after **addStuff** call so when you call **removeStuff** later, the **"photo" + index** value is already different.

Comment: I don't think so. I remove a bunch of stuff in a for loop, with all different indexes, but it stops at the first photo, which is photo0.

Comment: I've included more code. As it is now it stops in the first photo. If I remove the `removeChild(this["photo" + i]);` line, it removes all the other stuff.

Comment: Trace **"photo" + index** inside the **ldr_complete** method. I think all your photos are assigned to the same **index** value (which is **maxindex**).

Comment: Yes I tried this, but they do trace as photo0, photo1, photo2 and so on.

Comment: Well, now you have 2 options. 1. You can go on debugging it. Trace here, there and everywhere to have a complete understanding of what's going on there. A good and educational thing to do. Or. 2. You can redesign the architecture. If you don't actually need to access these bitmaps between the moment you load them and the moment you remove them, you can, instead of assigning them to **this** object members, keep them as an **Array** and remove them via the references from that **Array**.

Comment: Hmm. I do not need to access them between loading and removing, how can I store them in arrays?

Answer (score 2):

```
// Create the array.
var aList:Array = new Array;

function addStuff()
{
    // ...
    // Your code.
    var aLoader:Loader = new Loader;
    aLoader:Loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onBitmap);
    aLoader:Loader.load(new URLRequest(IMAGE_URL));
    // Your code.
    // ...
}

// Don't declare methods inside other methods.
function onBitmap(e:Event):void
{
    var anInfo:ContentLoaderInfo = e.target;
    var aRaster:Bitmap = anInfo.content as Bitmap;

    // Unsubscribe the listener.
    anInfo.removeEventListener(Event.INIT, onBitmap);

    // Store the reference.
    aList.push(aRaster);
    addChild(aRaster);
}

function deleteStuff():void
{
    while (aList.length)
    {
        var aRaster:Bitmap = aList.pop();

        removeChild(aRaster);

        // Release the loaded data.
        aRaster.bitmapData.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: @MagnusMyrgård I didn't check that, but in theory it should work, at least the removing part.